# Website not resolving on some networks : https://www.acquia.com/

Tags: dns, routing

Website not resolving: https://www.acquia.com/

Google dns lookup results: https://dns.google.com/query?name=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.acquia.com%2F

Some dns lookup shows no ip, examples:

https://www.nexcess.net/web-tools/dns-checker/: shows no result.

https://www.site24x7.com/find-ip-address-of-web-site.html: shows no result.

But some dns lookup shows the ip, examples:

https://www.whatismyip.com/dns-lookup/

https://www.uptrends.com/tools/find-ip-address-of-my-website

On Some networks the ip does resolve. Like mobile networks.

My question is, is there a way I can configure the ip found, on to my `/etc/hosts` and make it work? I tried setting `/etc/hosts` entry

50.16.202.230   acquia.com

but this didn't work for me.

Comment: It resolves to this host name when you look up the ip "ec2-50-16-202-230.compute-1.amazonaws.com"

Comment: You can map e.g. `50.16.202.230` to `acquia.com` in `/etc/hosts` but this won't prevent issues such as a physical outage along the route from you to the destination server.